# Enqueuing a script before anything else in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I wondered if it was possible to change the order in which a script is enqueued.

I ask this because I wish to include the [HTML5 enabling script](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/) but it needs to be included before any styles.

Is there any way to change the order?

I could obviously hard code it into the themes header, but I would prefer to enqueue it.

Thanks for any suggestions you may have.

Comment: Just FYI, I saw that you cross-posted this to the WordPress Stack Exchange as well.  Pick one site, this doesn't belong on both.

Comment: @EAMann Okay, sorry about that. I will stick to just stackoverflow.com from now on.

Comment: If it deals with WordPress, the WPSE is a good place for it. This question fits perfectly there. But if you were asking specifically about the HTML5 enabling script, it would belong here. It's a matter of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, WordPress writes out enqueued styles before it writes out enqueued scripts.  This is actually a good idea in the web design world because the styles are needed to render the page and should be downloaded before anything else that will block that (if you're waiting for a large script download before styles are loaded, the user will be presented with an ugly, unstyled page).

If you need to include something out of this order, hard-coding it before any styles or the call to `wp_head()` would be the easiest way.

Comment: I think I will stick to hard coding it, thank you for your answer!